# What does a http request without a protocol mean?

Tags: http, httprequest

What does a http request without a protocol mean?

So, if I do an HTTP request using telnet:

```
$ telnet myexample.com 80
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to myexample.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<html>
<head>
<title>Example Website</title>
</head>
<body>
</html>
```

Is that a valid HTTP request? And is that a valid HTTP response?

I think the server should probably close the connection.... But, I do not know anything about this yet.

The response does not return any HTTP headers at all. So, I am confused what is happening here.

I am using Apache!

Also, if I request the same for httpd.apache.org, (their main site):

```
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to httpd.apache.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https:///">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

That is, that they have messed up their server kind of. What in the world is happening here? Did everyone forget about such HTTP requests here?

NGINX seems to close connection. Found out by `telnet nginx.org 80`.

### Update:

This is HTTP/0.9? How can I disable HTTP/0.9 and HTTP/1.0?

Is it bad to disable them? Or is it ok to disable them?

Comment: GET / is not a valid HTTP request. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.

Comment: @JimFoye it is a HTTP/0.9 I am sure, a quick Google search shows it.

Comment: @JimFoye this is an example: https://medium.com/platform-engineer/evolution-of-http-69cfe6531ba0

Comment: You're right, lol - 0.9 is so old, I didn't even think about that.

Comment: So a 0.9 response doesn't have headers. It seems to me that Apache is honoring your 0.9 request (correctly, according to the 0.9 standard), and Nginx (at least the one you're talking to, as configured), is not. A web server can choose what versions of the HTTP protocol it supports.

Comment: @JimFoye :) right.